# How do I set up a NSPredicate to look for objects that have a nil attribute

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

I have a `ManagedObject class`, and one of the members of the class is a `NSDate`.  I would like to display all objects of the class for which the date is NOT set.  I tried using a predicate like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(date = NIL)"];
```

But I still get objects where the `date` is set.  What is the right way to set up a predicate for this?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

I think it's a case sensitivity issue. You can use "nil" or "NULL", but not "NIL". This works fine for me:

```
NSPredicate *eventWithNoEndDate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"endDate = nil"];
```

Comment: Do you know why the format should be @"endDate = nil" and not @"endDate == nil"?  I would have thought for sure it should be the double-equal-sign, but == doesn't produce the desired effect in this case.  Odd because other predicate comparisons do work with ==.

Comment: @kris I'm not sure. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW1 seems to suggest that `=` and `==` are equivalent, but the examples in http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001794-SW4 use `=`

Comment: thanks.  I am seeing that = and == are not behaving the same in this cirsumstance so heads up to everyone

Comment: How are they not the same?

Comment: kris, what is the difference?

Comment: According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html) `=` and `==` are equivalent within predicates

Answer (score 10):

Figured it out. Couldn't do it by using a predicate with a string format, so tried a predicate with a template and it worked.  Here's the code that gave me objects that had endDate set to NULL:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"endDate = $DATE"];
predicate = [predicate predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:
                   [NSDictionary  dictionaryWithObject:[NSNull null] forKey: @"DATE"]];
```

Comment: Frankly, I'd feel safer doing this than following the simpler example chrispix gives below, considering the syntactical irregularities of testing for null via predicates that he and kris discuss.

Comment: Thanks!! But how would you filter if it needs two filter variables? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001794-SW4

following code should work

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName = nil"];
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a super annoying behavior of fetch requests, as documented by Apple:

> If an object in a context has been modified, a predicate is evaluated against its modified state, not against the current state in the persistent store. Therefore, if an object in a context has been modified such that it meets the fetch request’s criteria, the request retrieves it even if changes have not been saved to the store and the values in the store are such that it does not meet the criteria. Conversely, if an object in a context has been modified such that it does not match the fetch request, the fetch request will not retrieve it even if the version in the store does match.

It's possible you're clearing the date elsewhere and the fetch request is including results where the date is `nil` in memory but still set on disk (in the persistent store), and so when the object faults it loads the object with the date set.

My only advice would be to coordinate access to the managed object context (say, on an `NSOperationQueue`) such that any updates are able to be saved to the persistent store before executing the fetch request.