# NSPredicate with boolean is not comparing a boolean to NO

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nspredicate

I'm using CoreData and my entity has a boolean property called "isReward".

I'm trying to fetch the entity and filter out all results where isReward == YES.

`isReward != YES` does not work.

`isReward == NO` does not work.

`NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:"isReward != %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]` does not work

`isReward == Nil` works.

What gives?

Comment: How did you declare the "isReward" property in your entity class?

Comment: It's an optional boolean with no default value. Is that why it is nil? I thought ([nilValue] != YES) would result to true.

Comment: Have you defined an Objective-C class for this entity? If yes, what does the definition of this class property look like?

Comment: @Christian IIRC, no default value means neither `NO` nor `YES`, this it is `nil`, and in the case of Core Data, `nil != NO`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I'm guessing you'll want:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isReward = NO OR isReward = nil"]
```

(Per the Apple docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001793-CJBDBHCB), direct comparison to `NO` should be valid.)

In general, when comparing to `null`/`nil` in data terms, `null == false` evaluates to `false` *and* `null != false` evaluates `false`. Comparison to `null` generally evaluates to `false`, except when testing for `IS NULL`.

I would also say that indexing in general gives you better results when you search for equality, not inequality. This is fairly simple to refactor to in your case (though I'm not sure that it will matter to Core Data in general).

Also, if you would like it to always be `YES` or `NO` (and skip the check for `nil`), you need to explicitly set the default to `NO`.

However, you may have some semantic value in leaving it `nil` until it is explicitly set by your application. This is really up to what you're trying to do.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I am pretty sure you need double equals instead of single equals in your solution.

Comment: `NSPredicate` syntax is more like SQL; since there is no need for an assignment operator, `=` and `==` are equivalent. See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW1.

Comment: And for some really weird reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749426/how-do-i-set-up-a-nspredicate-to-look-for-objects-that-have-a-nil-attribute#7799907

Comment: Is there a difference between doing `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"deleted = NO"]` versus `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"deleted = %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]]`?