# CKQuery using NSPredicate searching for NIL always throws an Invalid Expression error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate, cloudkit

On iOS 10.0.1 and Xcode 8.0, I have a `CKQuery` that is successfully returning data for a variety of conditions (`BEGINSWITH` and equal to certain strings, etc.). Now I'm looking specifically for records with a null value in one of the fields.

According to [Apple's Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001794-SW1), plus [How do I set up a NSPredicate to look for objects that have a nil attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749426/how-do-i-set-up-a-nspredicate-to-look-for-objects-that-have-a-nil-attribute) and [NSPredicate with boolean is not comparing a boolean to NO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209941/nspredicate-with-boolean-is-not-comparing-a-boolean-to-no?noredirect=1&lq=1), the following syntax should search for nil values:

```
NSPredicate *searchConditions = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"joiner = nil "];
CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:@"availableURLs"
                                           predicate:searchConditions];
```

When I set a breakpoint and examine `searchConditions`, it evaluates to `joiner == nil`. When I try to use it, the second line throws an exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CKException', reason: 
'Invalid predicate: joiner == nil (Error Domain=CKErrorDomain Code=12
"Invalid right expression in <joiner == nil>: <nil> is not a function expression" 
UserInfo={ck_isComparisonError=true, 
NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid right expression in <joiner == nil>: <nil> is not a function expression, 
NSUnderlyingError=0x1706516d0 {Error Domain=CKErrorDomain Code=12 "<nil> is not a function expression" 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=<nil> is not a function expression, ck_isComparisonError=true}}})'
```

I've tried every combination of `=`, `==`, `nil`, `Nil`, `NIL`, and `NULL`. All evaluate to `joiner == nil` and throw the exception.

In the first linked question, the OP uses `predicateWithSubstitutionVariables` to substitute in `[NSNull null]`. I tried that as well, but it evaluated again to `joiner == nil` and threw the same exception.

The Apple Docs have a section specifcally on searching for nil, and I can't see how their example differs from mine:

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName = nil"];
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I think the issue is more about `CKQuery` limitations that the `NSPredicate`, which would explain why you can use `nil` in `NSArray` of custom objects for instance... It's not clearly said, but from the Doc of `CKQuery`: `Building Your Predicates
An NSPredicate object defines the logical conditions for determining whether a record is a match for a query. The CKQuery class supports only a subset of the predicate behaviors offered by the full NSPredicate class.`

Comment: @Larme Thanks, I just re-read the ckquery docs more closely. I previously missed the bit about only supporting a subset if nspredicate. If you'll post that as an answer, I'll accept and maybe help the next person that didn't read the docs close enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [CKQuery doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckquery), it seems that `CKQuery` doesn't allow `nil` in predicates (in iOS 10 at the time of writing the answer).

> **Building Your Predicates**
>  An NSPredicate object defines the logical conditions for determining whether a record is a match for a
>   query. The CKQuery class supports only a subset of the predicate
>   behaviors offered by the full NSPredicate class.

Your `NSPredicate` construction didn't seem wrong, since it could work on `NSArray` of Custom Objects for instance.

Comment: So is there some other way to test for nil when building a predicate using CKQuery?