# NSPredicate string

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have a `NSPredicate` to use searching `Core Data`:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"objID == %@ AND createDate >= %@ AND createDate <= %@",self.objID, self.fromDate, self.toDate];
```

I want to expand this predicate to include the date range or if the "createDate" is nil. I'm not that familiar with SQL type searches.

Basiclly, I want to find all `Core Data` entities with objID and within the date range or nil.

```
if (objID == X && ((dateRange >= fromDate && dateRange <= toDate) || dateRange == nil))
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Did you try translating that into a predicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"objID == %@ AND (createDate >= %@ AND createDate <= %@ OR createDate = nil)",self.objID, self.fromDate, self.toDate];
```

I've just added `OR createDate = nil`.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749426/how-do-i-set-up-a-nspredicate-to-look-for-objects-that-have-a-nil-attribute) answer. Christopher Pickslay said, you can use "nil" or "NULL", but not "NIL".

Comment: I don't need to worry about group them like in a If stmt?

Comment: @Log139, NSPredicate groups statements according to algebra of logic. A AND B OR C equals (A AND B) OR C

Comment: Ok, so is this predicate grouping like `(objID = X AND createDate >= X AND createDate <= X) OR createDate = nil`?

Comment: @Log139, Yes, it is. Is it ok for you? If not, just add brackets in predicate's body

Comment: ok, thanks.  No, I need it like `objID == X AND ((AND createDate >= X AND createDate <= X) OR create = nil)` Do `()` work in predicates?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34461/discussion-between-valentin-shamardin-and-log139)