# How to remove nil object from NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c

My `NSMutableArray` contains the following data

```
<DoctorInfo: 0x15de99e0> (entity: DoctorInfo; id: 0x15defbe0 <x-coredata://39D9B/DoctorInfo/p8> ; data: {
    doctorName = nil;
    emailAdd = nil;
    hospitalName = nil;
    mobileNumber = nil;
    phoneNumber = nil;
}),
<DoctorInfo: 0x15de9b00> (entity: DoctorInfo; id: 0x15da5dc0 <x-coredata://39D9BED3/DoctorInfo/p10> ; data: {
    doctorName = nil;
    emailAdd = nil;
    hospitalName = nil;
    mobileNumber = nil;
    phoneNumber = nil;
})
)
```

How can I remove those objects with `nil`? I have tried the following code by changing `NSMutableArray` to the `NSArray` and then filter it but it is still not working:

```
 NSString *predString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(doctorName BEGINSWITH[cd] '%@')", nil];

    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predString];

     self.filteredDocInfoArray = [self.unfilteredDocInfoArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

Comment: NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(DoctorInfo * evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
                if (evaluatedObject.doctorName == nil) { return YES;
              } return NO;
        }];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You test for nil in predicate strings like this:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"doctorName = nil"];
```

See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001794-SW1) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a nil object to array. In your case you are adding an object that has some nil properties!

You can try this:

```
[yourArr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

    DoctorInfo *customObj = obj;
    if (customObj.doctorName) {
        //add obj to temp array
    }
}];
```

Now you can replace yourArr with tempArr

If you want to use NSPredicate, please refer [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749426/how-do-i-set-up-a-nspredicate-to-look-for-objects-that-have-a-nil-attribute)